# website not loading on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, magento

I'm working on a magento site and since last week it won't load in any iOS device anymore.
When I try to open it in either safari or chrome I get a message saying:

`"A problem occurred with this web page so it was reloaded"`

I've tried this on an iphone 6 plus as well as on an ipad mini 2 both running iOS 9.3.4

I've opened the console on both firefox and chrome they both don't give any errors. The site also seems to work without any problems when I try to open it on a mac with safari. I had a co-worker open it up on his android phone and again no problems here. I tried clearing all my safari history and data in my ipad multiple times but this didn't change anything.

I've also tried to disable javascript to determine if this was the problem. This also didn't change anything.

Does anyone know what could be going on? I'm just trying to figure out what could possible cause this

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your .plist file

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I think you are confused. This is regarding a magento website that I'm trying to open on an iOS device. It isn't regarding an actual iOS application. So there is no .plist file

Comment: You are open in safari or you have created application in that you are opening?

Comment: I'm just trying to open the website in safari. So this isn't regarding app development

Comment: You have hosted your website in local or public environment?

Comment: public environment

Comment: give link. Let me check it is open in my device or not. I have iPhone 6 with 9.3.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120486/discussion-between-nosixties-and-bhadresh-mulsaniya).